# python-xmpp received message

Tags: python, xmpp, google-talk

I wrote application with xmpp. It  sending message using gtalk. I want to print received message. How can i do? My application short code as follows.

```
def process_message():
    client = xmpp.Client('gmail.com')
    client.connect( server=('talk.google.com',5223) )
    client.auth(user,passwd, 'botty')

    to = raw_input("to: ");
    if client:
        message = raw_input("message: ")
        client.send( xmpp.Message( to,message ) )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = raw_input("User: ")
    passwd = getpass.getpass("Pass: ")
    process_message()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register an event handler for incoming messages, using [`Client.registerHandler`](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/xmpp.dispatcher.Dispatcher-class.html#RegisterHandler). Have a look at sample client code like [this](http://off-the-stack.moorman.nu/2012-10-10-keep-in-touch-with-your-servers-using-xmpp.html) or [this one](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/examples/xtalk.py). For instance, the latter implements the message handler function like this:

```
def xmpp_message(self, con, event):
    type = event.getType()
    fromjid = event.getFrom().getStripped()
    if type in ['message', 'chat', None] and fromjid == self.remotejid:
        sys.stdout.write(event.getBody() + '\n')
```